# Consume 'Free' memory on linux machine on the expense of cache

Tags: caching, memory, free

When using the tool 'free' in linux, we can see several values of memory aspects:

```
[root@coconut-stateless-clients-5 ~] 2021-08-03 17:28:07 $ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       62907052      382180    61985152        4788      539720    61933812
Swap:             0           0           0
```

I need to lower the 'free' memory value and keep 'available' value unchanged (as much as I can)
How can I 'fill' up the cache memory on the expense of 'free' in a linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

Cache memory is filled by the kernel in various cases. Usually the operating system stores binaries or other files it currently works with. For example, data that is displayed, or sent to other machines is kept in the cache memory.

That mechanism can be used in order to load files or data to the cache. Hence, achieving both goals of reducing 'free' memory and filling 'cache'.

For that we can use the BSD reading tool 'head' that is used for reading **lines** or **bytes** from file.
The **lines** or **bytes** can be read to memory and then will be loaded to cache only momentarily. Or, can be read to a file and the data read and cached in memory until the memory is required for other purpose (and no other space left).

With the help of [this article](https://medium.com/marionete/linux-disk-cache-was-always-there-741bef097e7f) you can get more familiar with the details. But the following example is suffice if you just want to achieve the goals.

Fill 'cache' with x GiB/MiB of data and reduce 'free' with the same space:

2GiB example:

```
# head -c 2G /dev/urandom > dummy.file
```

250MiB example:

```
# head -c 250M /dev/urandom > dummy.file
```

In order to free up **ALL** the cached space, run this command:

```
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```